# Play two animations together on Spinner

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to play moving and rotation animations on Spinner game object. For rotation I have used animator controller and for movement I have written code.

Here is animator controller inspector settings for rotation:

[image]

Here is the code that I have written for movement:

```
private void StartMoving()
{
    iTween.MoveBy(gameObject, iTween.Hash("x", transformDistance, "time", 
        Random.Range(1.5f, 5f), "looptype", iTween.LoopType.pingPong, "easetype", 
        iTween.EaseType.linear, "delay", Random.Range(0f, 1f)));
}
```

At present only movement related action, I am showing in game play, rotation completely get stopped. If I set Apply Root Motion flag to false then rotation animation start playing and movement get stopped.

I want to play both animations together.

Here you have spinner object details:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anytime you are combining an animation via the Animation controller and some other animation/motion via script it's best to separate those two objects (into parent child objects) as these two effects will conflict with each other.

Yes you could try some `Apply root motion` and other fancy stuff but it's always messy and I've found that separating them is cleaner and simpler.

In your case

1. Create a parent object and put your motion effect on that
2. Create a child object with your rotation object and animate it as you want.

Because the animation is now on the child object it wont be affected by the motion on parent.

Comment: You can also move both with the same animator, add the animator on the parent and that allow you to animate all children